# Binding to a Xamarin Listview via web service

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am trying to launch a interface method and bind it to a Xamarin list view but I am having some trouble. My interface is below

```
  readonly string url = "http://myinternaliis/api/";
  readonly IHttpService httpService;

  public ApiClient(IHttpService httpService)
  {
       this.httpService = httpService;
  }

  public Task<List<JobsList>> GetJobs() => httpService.Get<List<JobsList>>($"{url}job");
```

I am trying to bind it to my list view as such please correct me if this is wrong. Should I be creating a collection of some description

```
public partial class JobsPage : ContentPage
{
    readonly string url = "http://myinternaliis/api/";
    public IHttpService httpService;
    public IApi FuleApiClient;

    public JobsPage ()
    {
        InitializeComponent ();

        FuelApiClient _client = new FuelApiClient(httpService);

        this.JobListing.ItemsSource =   _client.GetJobs();
    }
```

Comment: What is your problem? Do you get an exception? Have you debugged it and are there some items loaded or is the list count zero? Or are there items and just the listview isn't showing anything? It could be helpful to see your XAML code as well.

Comment: You're returning a `Task`. So you should use await to get the actual result. However, you are calling the `GetJobs` method from your constructor which doesn't allow async/await calls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to await your task.

```
public partial class JobsPage : ContentPage
    {
        readonly string url = "http://myinternaliis/api/";
        public IHttpService httpService;
        public IApi FuleApiClient;

        public JobsPage ()
        {
        InitializeComponent ();


         FuelApiClient _client = new FuelApiClient(httpService);

         SetItemSource();

        }

        private Task SetItemSource()
    .   {
    .       JobListing.ItemsSource =   await _client.GetJobs();
        }
    }
```